# ¿QUe debo hacer si no me abre menu conteptual de wamp server?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

he instalado wampserver se habilitan todos los servicios (se pone en verde) pero cuando le doy boton derecho para abrir phpmyadmin no muestra nada.

he instalado par de veces y no falla nada en la instalaciòn

alguna sugerencia¿?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oye y ya intentaste acceder desde la URL? Por ejemplo:
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

Comment: no habia intentado si sale activado

Comment: me sale la pagina phpmyadmin pero no se cual es la clave

Comment: Si no has cambiando la configuración los mas probable es que sea "root" o 1234

Comment: era user root y pass vacio   gracias te califique para agradecer